# How many distinct prime ideals in $\mathbb Z/p^2q\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many distinct prime ideals are there in $\mathbb Z/p^2q\mathbb Z$ , where $p,q$ are distinct primes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $\ell\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $\ell \mid n$, and $\ell$ prime. Now $n=p^2q$. This should help you with the answer.

Comment: If the ring is a PID then prime ideals are maximal ideal. Since Z_n is not a PID so how many maximal ideals are there for this ring??